# Awake Devexpress component by Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, callback, webforms, asp.net-ajax

I use devextreme for asp.net web forms. I catch my **mahID** by debug on my metod. I wanna do postback on serverside like refresh i donno.

I can tell what happening on my server side the all **components dont load** what i have on aspx design side. How can i awake my labels,charts etc.

THANKS.

C# Server Side

```
 public void MahalleBilgileriGetir(int mahalleId)
    {
        View_MuhtarBursaMahalle mahalle = View_MuhtarBursaMahalle.BursaMahalleGetir(mahalleId);

        if (mahalle != null)
        {
            lblMuhtarlikAdi.Text = string.Format("{0}  -  {1}", mahalle.MahalleAdi, mahalle.IlceAdi);
            lblMuhtar.Text = string.Format("{0}", mahalle.AdSoyad);
            lblCepTelefon.Text = string.Format("{0}", mahalle.Telefon);
            lblDonemi.Text = string.Format("{0}", mahalle.Donemi);
            flMuhtar.Visible = true;

            ChartNufus.DataSource = chartNufusBul(mahalle.MahalleAdi, mahalle.ErkekNufusu, mahalle.KadinNufusu, mahalle.ToplamNufusu);
            ChartNufus.DataBind();
            ChartTitle chartTitle = new ChartTitle() { Text = string.Format("{0} Toplam Nüfusu: {1}", mahalle.MahalleAdi, mahalle.ToplamNufusu.HasValue ? mahalle.ToplamNufusu.Value : 0) };
            ChartNufus.Titles.Clear();
            ChartNufus.Titles.Add(chartTitle);
            ChartNufus.Visible = true;

            SecimBilgileriGetir(mahalleId, mahalle.MahalleAdi);
            VergiGelirleriGetir(mahalleId, mahalle.MahalleAdi, mahalle.ToplamNufusu);
            chartSecim2014.Visible = true;
            chartSecim2018.Visible = true;
            chartSecim2019.Visible = true;
        }}
```

JS

```
if (mah_adi !== undefined) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "MahalleBilgileri.aspx/MahalleBilgileriGetir",
                    data: '{mahID: "' + e.target.attribute("mahid") + '" }',
                    async: false,
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response) {
                            console.log("ajax", response);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome. What do you mean by “awake” in this context? Are you trying to get the components to load? To render? To do something?

Comment: Thank you Jeremy. Yes exactly i want load components. 
I send my param to method but component dont load page dont reload.